# Google API app engine redirect uri

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-calendar-api

can someone point me in the right direction re: redirect uri

right now i have app hosted on appspot (nothing done or uploaded to it at this point)

"Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it."

do i need to upload anything for this to work?

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp#choosingredirecturi

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4/v6xr77ewYqhvHSyW6UJ1w7jKwAzu&
client_id=8819981768.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret={client_secret}&
redirect_uri=https://oauth2-login-demo.appspot.com/code&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

i just want to authenticate so that i can use the calendar api

Answer (score 0):

1. Do upload the application. I am not sure what you mean by saying that the app is hosted on appspot but nothing done or uploaded at this point. So, first make sure that you have uploaded a version of your application.
2. The OAuth process is redirecting the flow if I understand correct to `oauth2-login-demo.appspot.com` and you must have registered this callback url when setting up your application.
3. So it seems that the redirection is probably taking place but you are seeing the General Exception that is normally thrown by App Engine.
4. You should look into the Admin Console -> Logs for your application to understand the reason for the failure. You might get some information there about the cause.
5. If there is a problem with your code, it will point that in the logs. Alternately, put in some exception handlers and bump up the Log Level to INFO in your logging.properties to have a better chance of tracking down the root case.